# iPhone-friendly alternative to recursion over huge tree structures?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, algorithm, recursion

I have a graph of objects of the same type. Every object is linked with 0, 1 or many others. I need to walk through all possible paths in the graph.

Now I could do that with recursion, but there is the danger of a stack overflow. There can be tens of thousands of them.

I've heard there are better ways than recursion where a method keeps calling itself over and over again.

What do the alternatives look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something along the lines of:

(let's presume TreeNode contains a property NSArray * children)

```
-(void)iterateOverTree:(TreeNode *)node
{
    NSMutableArray * elements = [NSMutableArray array];
    [elements addObject:node];

    while([elements count])
    {
        TreeNode * current = [elements objectAtIndex:0];
        [self doStuffWithNode:current];
        for(TreeNode * child in current.children)
        {
            [elements addObject:child];
        }

        [elements removeObjectAtIndex:0];
    }
}
```

Beware, untested code :)

Answer (score 1):

You can "imitate" stack by yourself, storing current state in a NSArray. That will allow to use heap instead of stack memory and, possibly, workaround stack overflow issue.

Comment: Joris Mans' answer gives an overview of what you can write. Every structure needs slightly different code.