# How to modify this tree iteration code to iterate in an ordered way?

Tags: objective-c, recursion, graph, iteration

This piece of code iterates over a tree of TreeNode objects where every object may have childs (from an Answer to this question: [iPhone-friendly alternative to recursion over huge tree structures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5777329/iphone-friendly-alternative-to-recursion-over-huge-tree-structures)).

```
-(void)iterateOverTree:(TreeNode *)node
{
    NSMutableArray * elements = [NSMutableArray array];
    [elements addObject:node];

    while([elements count])
    {
        TreeNode * current = [elements objectAtIndex:0];
        [self doStuffWithNode:current];
        for(TreeNode * child in current.children)
        {
            [elements addObject:child];
        }

        [elements removeObjectAtIndex:0];
    }
}
```

The problem is that this code does not walk through the tree in an ordered way.

i.E. I have this:
A owns B, J
B owns C owns D owns E
J owns K owns L owns M
(note: "owns" means "has child". A has two childs while the rest has one or none)

This is how the tree is traversed: A, B, J, C, K, D, L, ...

But I want: 
A, B, C, D, E, 
J, K, L, M, ...

in an ordered way, just like it happens with recursion.

How could I change that in such a way that it traverses the tree ordered, like in the example above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want [depth first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search). Currently you're performing [breadth first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search).

I don't know Objective-C, but it looks like you're using NSMutableArray [as a queue](http://sg80bab.blogspot.com/2008/05/nsmutablearray-makes-awesome-cocoa.html). Use it as a stack for non-recursive depth first search.

Comment: Do you have an example for a depth first search? I don't need the FIFO queue, right? So how'd I remove that from the code above?

Comment: loads of examples online: http://faculty.simpson.edu/lydia.sinapova/www/cmsc250/LN250_Weiss/L24-BreadthDepth.htm http://renaud.waldura.com/portfolio/graph-algorithms/ etc. I'm guessing you need to do `removeLastObject`, but check with someone who actually knows Objective-C to be sure...

Comment: @BugAlert - Mr E is right. All you really need is to remove the last object every time from the queue (instead of the first object, as you are doing now). 'removeLastObject' should work for you. Your code will do the following - 1. remove last object 2. do something with it 3. add all the children